# Laravel full URL routing

Tags: url-routing, laravel

How can I set my routes depending on the domain-name? I want to register some actions to diffenrent domain-names (not sub-domains).

Example of the functionality I need to replicate:

```
Route::any('www.domain1.com', 'Controler@Action1'); 
Route::any('www.domain2.com', 'Controler@Action2');
```

I can't use URL rewriting in .htaccess because I store domain->route maping in my database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you can do it like this

```
Route::group(array('domain'=>'www.domain1.com'), function(){
    Route::get('/',array('as'=>'domain1Home', 'uses'=>'Controller@Action1'));
});

Route::group(array('domain'=>'www.domain2.com'), function(){
    Route::get('/',array('as'=>'domain2Home', 'uses'=>'Controller@Action2'));
});
```

you can know more about that from http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing its some how the same way of thinking ..