# Hosting two different applications running on Laravel 4 on shared hosting

Tags: php, dns, laravel

I'm about to start development of a site using Laravel4 that will include a cms hosted on a sub-domain.  What I want to know if is there is a way to have the main Laravel installation shared between the two apps?

I've had various success in testing using the following example: [Laravel full URL routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132209/laravel-full-url-routing), however I want to keep the functionality from the app folder separate and have something like say, app_main, app_cms that holds the relevant models, views and controllers for each site in there.

There doesn't seem to be much help that I can find in how to set up Laravel for such a requirement, so any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a multihosting solution, which after logging into FTP contains this folders:

```
domaina.com
domainb.com
domainc.com
```

If I'd like to share same Laravel code between those websites,
I just create 'Laravel' folder on the same level, so it looks just like this:

```
domaina.com
domainb.com
domainc.com
laravel
```

This 'laravel' folder holds everything except 'app' & 'public' directory.

I just place content of 'public' directory right inside 'domaina.com' folder (for example).
Open up 'index.php' and adjust these lines to match actual location.
Now you are good to go

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

Comment: This one looked the most appealing to me and after having played about, finally got this method to work.  I had to change the paths.php file within the bootstrap folder, specifically setting the 'base' => __DIR__.'/../..' and including my workbench folder in the new domain folder, all in all, this done the trick.
Kudos to the others who provided solutions, haven't tried them but thanks for the input nonetheless, gave me a few to consider.

Comment: @andreyco I have same situation , I have a website www.ideconnect.com which is basically questionair , Now I want to upload another similar website with the sub domian of the ideconnect some how can you please help me out with this . 

For the current website I kept the content of Public folder in the my website public folder and rest in another folder outside the publuic folder .

Answer (score 0):

`bootstrap/paths.php` holds the main folder definitions. For each instance, you can alter the app folder, public folder, base folder, storage folder and so on from the file.

You can set a cookie/session, or check domain etc. for main and subdomain and alter it like:

```
'app' => Session::has('subdomain')?'../../app':__DIR__.'/../app',
```

Answer (score 0):

use Router for this.

e.g.

```
Route::group(array('domain'=>'example.com'), function(){
//Define the routes for example.com
});

Route::group(array('domain'=>'cms.example.com'), function(){
//Define the routes for cms.example.com
});
```

for easier maintanace, you can use namespace for controllers.

e.g. your controller folder can look like this

```
App
|
|---Controllers
    |-- site
        |
        |-----HomeController.php

    |-- subdomain
        |
        |-----HomeController.php
```

now, for site controllers, use a namspace like, `<?php namespace site;?>`

for subdomain controllers, use a namespace like `<?php namespace subdomain;?>`

in the routes file, define the routes as,

```
Route::group(array('domain'=>'example.com'), function(){
    Route::get('/', array(
       'as' => 'index',
       'uses' => '\site\HomeController@index'
    ))
});
```

for subdomains,

```
Route::group(array('domain'=>'cms.example.com'), function(){
    Route::get('/', array(
       'as' => 'cms.index',
       'uses' => '\subdomain\HomeController@index'
    ))
});
```

plain and simplest way.