# Hosting two different applications running on Laravel 4 on shared hosting - part 2

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get two sites running off one installation of Laravel, one as the main site and one contained within a sub-domain.  I initially posed the following question: [Hosting two different applications running on Laravel 4 on shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179256/hosting-two-different-applications-running-on-laravel-4-on-shared-hosting), and I thought I'd cracked it until I ran into a strange error.

I'm running the sites on shared hosting under the following structure...

```
/private/
    app1/
        app/
        bootstrap/
        workbench/
    app2/
        app/
        bootstrap/
        workbench/
    vendor/

/public_html/
    css/
    js/
    app2/
        css/
        js/
```

Now, I've created the sub-domain and I can get access to it via the browser, however, when I load the site it fire back the following Laravel error message.

> View [layout] not found.

Problem is, this is the main layout template for app1 NOT app2.  I've hard coded the full host path in /public_html/app2/index.php to point to /private/app2/bootstrap/autoload.php 
...and likewise within the /private/app2/bootstrap/start.php I've also hardcoded the full path but it still looks for the main app1 site.

Can't seem to figure out exactly what to alter to get the sub-domain to point to the app2 folder.  Any tips to the obvious here would be great.

Comment: Where does "layout" live?

Comment: Hi Phil, layout is in the main app1 views folder as the default template.
I've managed to get this working in the meantime by uploading a copy of the vendor folder to the private/app2 folder and hard coding some of the links to point to this, so I'll have another play at trying to get it to point to the main private/vendor folder as I'd prefer to have the one core framework folder if possible.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a separate environment for the sub domain?  Then use conditionals based on the environment name. http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following structure?

```
/private/
    app1/
            app/
            bootstrap/
            workbench/
    app2/
            app/
            bootstrap/
            workbench/
    vendor/

/public_html_main/
    css/
    js/

/public_html_subdomain/
    css/
    js/
```